# Merge the results of two active record queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to merge the results from the following queries:

```
Dispenser.includes(:reviews).where.not(reviews: { id: nil })
```

and

```
Dispenser.includes(:dispenser_reviews).where.not(dispenser_reviews: { id: nil })
```

I have tried simply placing a `||` in the middle of these two queries, but that does not give the expected result. I want to find all Dispensers with a `review` or a `dispenser_review`..

So let's say I have the following dispenser ids from each query:

`[1, 2, 3]` and `[2, 3, 4]` ..

The output should be the dispensers represented by the ids `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that using https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel rather than active record.  It provides the more advanced functionality that Arel does not have out of the box.

That being said, your logic is gonna be pretty nasty.  If you wanted to get the result set and you didn't mind two queries instead of one, I'd just join the two results with the `+` operator.

```
r1 = Dispenser.includes(:reviews)# ...
r2 = Dispenser.includes(:dispenser_reviews)# ...
result = r1 + r2
```

As for a squeel example, it'd be something like:

```
Dispenser.includes{reviews}.
  includes{dispenser_reviews}.
  where{(reviews.id.not_eq nil) | {dispenser_reviews.id.not_eq nil)}.
  references(:all)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate to show how this would be done using squeel? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I think you've solved it for me it's (r1+r2).uniq

Comment: Here is my model scope for Dispenser   scope :with_reviews, -> { ( includes(:reviews).where.not(reviews: { id: nil }) + includes(:dispenser_reviews).where.not(dispenser_reviews: { id: nil }) ).uniq }

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure it'd work inside of a scope, Perhaps so.  If not, you can also just define a class method with the same logic.

Comment: It seems to work.. the result sets have some overlap, but the output count is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Joins will do an INNER JOIN and only return dispenser objects that have reviews or dispenser_reviews.  Pipe '|' will get rid of dups.

```
Dispenser.joins(:reviews) | Dispenser.joins(:dispenser_reviews)
```

or to get ids

```
Dispenser.joins(:reviews).pluck(:id) | Dispenser.joins(:dispenser_reviews).pluck(:id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use arel and combine the two queries into one like this:

```
Dispenser.includes(:reviews, :dispenser_reviews).where((Review.arel_table[:id].not_eq(nil)).or DispenserReview.arel_table[:id].not_eq(nil)).references(:reviews, :dispenser_reviews)
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'reviews.id' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `dispensers`  WHERE ((`reviews`.`id` IS NOT NULL OR `dispenser_reviews`.`id` IS NOT NULL))

Comment: On re-reading your error, the above query (in answer) can not generate the sql query shown in your error. I will suggest replicating it exactly! If you want a count, please add a `.count` at the end of the query.